# Chamar uma tab (javascript) através de outra página

Tags: javascript

tenho uma página chamada Produtos. Essa página tem um grupo de tabs.
POR EX: tab 1, tab 2 e tab 3). 
Tenho na Home um link que precisa chamar a página produtos e com a tab2 já aberta. Como faço?

A chamada da tab2 na página Produtos é Tab 2

O Javascript:

```
 <script language="javascript">
    function MyFunction(divName){

    //hidden val
    var hiddenVal = document.getElementById("tempDivName"); 

    //hide old
    if(hiddenVal.Value != undefined){
        var oldDiv = document.getElementById(hiddenVal.Value); 
        oldDiv.style.display = 'none'; 
    }

    //show div
        var tempDiv = document.getElementById(divName); 
        tempDiv.style.display = 'block';              

    //save div ID
        hiddenVal.Value = document.getElementById(divName).getAttribute("id");

    }
</script>
```

HTML da página Produtos :

```
    <input id="tempDivName" type="hidden" />
    <a href="#" OnClick="MyFunction('myDiv1');"><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-8214" src="http://totalmed.net.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/icons_geis_correlatos.jpg" alt="icons_geis_correlatos" width="166" height="96" /></a>
<a href="#" OnClick="MyFunction('myDiv2');"><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-8215" src="http://totalmed.net.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/icons_ginecologia_obstetricia.jpg" alt="icons_ginecologia_obstetricia" width="166" height="96" /></a>
<a href="#" OnClick="MyFunction('myDiv3');"><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-8221" src="http://totalmed.net.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/icons_suporte_vida.jpg" alt="icons_suporte_vida" width="166" height="96" /></a>

[text_divider type="double"]
<h1>Produtos</h1>
[/text_divider]

<!-- AQUI COMEÇA UM GRUPO DE TAB -->

    <div id="myDiv1" style="display: none;">

    [column width="1/1" last="true" title="Geis e Correlatos" title_type="single" animation="from-left" implicit="true"]

    [tabs layout="vertical" nav_color="accent1" left_color="accent2" right_color="accent4"]
    [tab icon="" title="Acessórios"]

[/column_1]

[column_1 width="1/2" last="true" title="" title_type="single" animation="none" implicit="true"]

<img class="size-full wp-image-7604 aligncenter" src="http://totalmed.net.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/geis.png" alt="geis" width="314" height="314" />

[/column_1]
[/tab]

[tab icon="" title="Higienizador Íntimo"]

[blank h="60"]

[/blank]   

[/column]

</div>

    <!-- AQUI COMEÇA UM GRUPO DE TAB -->

    <div id="myDiv2" style="display: none;">

[column width="1/1" last="true" title="Ginecologia e Obstetrícia" title_type="single" animation="from-left" implicit="true"]

[tabs layout="vertical" nav_color="accent1" left_color="accent2" right_color="accent4"]
[tab icon="" title="Cânulas / Cateters / Guias"]    

This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean

sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum.     
    </div>

    <!-- AQUI COMEÇA UM GRUPO DE TAB -->

    <div id="myDiv3" style="display: none;">

[column width="1/1" last="true" title="Suporte à vida" title_type="single" animation="from-left" implicit="true"]

[tabs layout="vertical" nav_color="accent1" left_color="accent2" right_color="accent4"]
[tab icon="" title="Analisadores e Simuladores"]    

[column_1 width="1/2" last="true" title="" title_type="single" animation="none" implicit="true"]

<img class="size-full wp-image-7604 aligncenter" src="http://totalmed.net.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/suporte.png" alt="Suporte à vida" width="314" height="314" />

[/column_1]
[/tab]
[/tabs]

[/column]
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tenho bem a certeza de como o wordpress interpreta isto mas testa assim:

Usa no URL qual a tab que queres abrir. Da mesma maneira que usas `OnClick="MyFunction('myDiv1');` podes usar um URL que tenha uma *query string* assim:

```
meu.site.com/pasta/subpasta/?tab=myDiv1
```

e no arranque da página usas, no JS, assim:

```
var queryString = location.search.slice(1);
var tab = queryString.match(/tab=(\w+)/);
if (tab) MyFunction(tab[1]);
```

Assim ele vai procurar no URL por `tab=xxx` e caso haja vai chamar a função com o nome da tab.